# How to invoke Abbyy fine reader through command line or any API?

Tags: ocr, abbyy, finereader

I need to convert the .tif image to .pdf using Abbyy fine reader in my website. Could anyone tell me the required commands executed in command line or call the API using ajax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FineReader is not meant to be used like that. For websites, you are expected to use ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK.